telegram bot using python-telegram-bot django
I have a Telegram bot using the python-telegram-bot library and Django. The bot is run and messages are processed via a webhook pythonanywhere. I used the free plan and the bot was working perfectly, but I needed to upgrade the account to access external sites. After upgrading to the Hacker plan, issues started occurring with message processing and improper tracking.
How can I resolve this issue? Could it be related to high CPU usage or SSH settings?
Thank you.
....................

Please, add more information, or error messages


After upgrading to the Hacker plan, issues started occurring with message processing and improper tracking.

You need to provide exact error messages or define the issues you are experiencing in detail.

but I needed to upgrade the account to access external sites. After upgrading to the Hacker plan, issues started occurring

Sherlocking my way through this, I understand you started fetching data from external sources via your app. You may be getting rate limited due to too many requests to a resource from a single IP.

Thank you for your response... The problem occurs when entering the ConversationHandler values ​​and sending a message. There is a delay in processing the message for the first time, then when re-sending the value is saved. I think the problem is from 2,000 CPU-seconds because there is not a big difference between the free plan and the hacker plan
